# tried to install laravel by composer getting error

Tags: php, laravel-7

followed this 
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation

> Cloning failed using an ssh key for authentication, enter your GitHub credentials to access private repos
>   Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+on+DESKTOP-SGKEVL0+2020-05-11+0736
>   to retrieve a token. It will be stored in "C:/Users/JK/AppData/Roaming/Composer/auth.json" for future use by Composer.
>   Token (hidden)

I don't have github account

can any one help me with this 
Thanks in advance

Comment: So you're trying to clone a private repository, but you're not allowed to do that, since you aren't logged in to see that private one.

Comment: @Qirel, Laravel uses a public repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry friends but got the solution I tried again and detected that it was due to a slow internet connection
I noticed once I got the same error when my net was not working

Answer (score 0):

If someone is getting the same error, as i was, the folder you're creating your project might be owned by another user (e.g root).

I was trying to do `composer create-project laravel/lumen .` (attention to the dot on the end, as i was trying to install on the folder i was in) on a docker container, but was having the same error saying that i needed a key to clone a private repo, which was odd. One thing i found in the internet is that you might not have Git installed, but i did. So i entered the container with `--user=root` instead and the installation succeeded.

After that i found out that the folder i was trying to install was owned by root, did a chown and chgrp, tried again, this time with the desired user and everything went normal.